# Issue with maintaining session between main domain and subdomains in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP 1.3 and I have 1 main domain `http://www.domain.com` with subdomain `http://subdomain.domain.com`, I have done many research and add following code in `app/config/bootstrap.php`:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

And set in `app/config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for php and it is working, try this.

```
 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
 session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted this code in both domain (main domain & sub domain) in /app/config/core.php file. Its working fine.

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();